# Unable to change the default printer

Tags: printing, cups

When I use the command

```
$ sudo lpoptions -d Deskjet-F300-series
```

it won't change the default printer.

```
$ lpstat -a
Deskjet-F300-series accepting requests since Sun 10 Apr 2011 11:02:12 AM CEST
Deskjet-F4200-series accepting requests since Mon 04 Apr 2011 03:39:17 PM CEST
Deskjet_F4200 accepting requests since Mon 04 Apr 2011 03:39:17 PM CEST
HP_Deskjet_F4200_series accepting requests since Mon 04 Apr 2011 03:39:17 PM CEST

$ lpstat -d
system default destination: HP_Deskjet_F4200_series

$ lpstat -p
printer Deskjet-F300-series is idle.  enabled since Sun 10 Apr 2011 11:02:12 AM CEST
    Printer is now online.
printer Deskjet-F4200-series disabled since Mon 04 Apr 2011 03:39:17 PM CEST -
    Unplugged or turned off
printer Deskjet_F4200 disabled since Mon 04 Apr 2011 03:39:17 PM CEST -
    Unplugged or turned off
printer HP_Deskjet_F4200_series disabled since Mon 04 Apr 2011 03:39:17 PM CEST -
    Unplugged or turned off
```

Do you know where is the fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo lpoptions -d` sets the system-wide default printer (by editing `/etc/cups/lpoptions`). You may also have a per-user default printer, which overrides the system-level setting. The per-user default is stored in `~/.cups/lpoptions`; you can change it with `lpoptions -d`.